# How to see logs out of tests running Substrate Cumulus based runtime?

Tags: logging, automated-tests, substrate, polkadot

I have test. It runs full runtime. I sure there are logs along the stack. But I cannot see them in output.

I run test like that:

```
RUST_LOG=trace,parity-db=error,trie=error,runtime=trace,substrate-relay=trace,bridge=trace cargo ltest my_runtime::xcm_test -- --nocapture
```

What should I do to see logs in tests?

Comment: Hi Dzmitry, please take a look at the Substrate StackExchange proposal and support it: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Answer (score 1, accepted):

substrate uses usual next logger

```
/// this must be singleton
#[cfg(test)]
pub fn env_logger_init() {
    let _ = env_logger::builder().is_test(true).try_init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

println!("Hello world {:#?} {:?}", who, balance);